# Notice: Undefined index en un login con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli, login

estoy creando un sistema en donde se pueden hacer 2 logins, administrador y profesor. El login de Administrador funciona, pero en caso de que el usuario o contraseña sean incorrectos, me marca dicho error. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero en el Login de Profesor de plano siempre me marca ese error. La tabla Administrador tiene 4 campos, la tabla profesor tiene 9, ambas tablas tienen contraseñas hash. Para validar, en Administrador uso el campo 'usuario' y 'contraseña'. En profesor uso el 'id_profesor' que es la llave primaria y 'contraseñaprofesor' para validar el ingreso pero como dije, en Administrador funciona y en profesor siempre me marca error aunque el Id y la contraseña sean correctos.

este es el formulario html

```
    <form class="login-form" action="checklogin_profe.php" method="post">
  <input name="num" type="text" id="num" required placeholder="Numero de Empleado">
  <input name="contra" type="password" id="contra" required placeholder="Contraseña">
   <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
</form>
```

y aqui el checklogin_profe.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
$host_db = "localhost";
$user_db = "root";
$pass_db = "";
$db_name = "tutorias";
$tbl_name = "profesor";
$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);
  if ($conexion->connect_error) {
  die("No se pudo conectar a la Base de Datos: " . $conexion->connect_error);
  }
 $usenum = $_POST['num'];
 $pass = $_POST['contra'];
 $sql = "SELECT contraseñaprofe FROM profesor WHERE id_profesor = '$usenum'";
 $result = $conexion->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    
 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
  if (password_verify($pass, $row['contraseñaprofe'])) {
     $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     $_SESSION['start'] = time();
     $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);
     echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
     echo "<br><br><a href=home_profes.php>Panel de Control</a>";    
     }
    else {
    echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";
    echo "<br><a href='login_profe.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
     }  
  mysqli_close($conexion);
  ?>
```

además tengo mi formulario login de administrador

```
    <form class="login-form" action="checklogin.php" method="post">
  <input name="username" type="text" id="username" required placeholder="Usuario">
  <input name="password" type="password" id="password" required placeholder="Contraseña">
   <button type="submit">Entrar</button>

</form>
```

y su checklogin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
$host_db = "localhost";
$user_db = "root";
$pass_db = "";
$db_name = "tutorias";
$tbl_name = "administrador";
$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);
  if ($conexion->connect_error) {
  die("No se pudo conectar a la Base de Datos: " . $conexion->connect_error);
  }
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM administrador WHERE usuario = '$username'";
 $result = $conexion->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    
 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
  if (password_verify($password, $row ['contraseña2'])) {
     $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     $_SESSION['start'] = time();
     $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);
     echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
     echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>";  
     }
    else {
    echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";
    echo "<br><a href='login.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
     }  
  mysqli_close($conexion);
  ?>
```

en el caso de profesor solo copie los formularios y las clases php y las adapté pero me manda siempre 
"Notice: Undefined index: contraseñaprofe in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tuto\checklogin_profe1.php on line 21"
¿Qué estará fallando?

Comment: ¿Probaste con usar contrasena profe en vez de contraseñaprofe?

Comment: Tendrías que hacer más tests para determinarlo. Saca por pantalla un mensaje en el caso de que `num_rows > 0` para saber si está recibiendo filas o no. Si está devolviendo filas, puede ser interesante que saques por pantalla el objeto `$row` para ver que contiene.

Comment: Por lo que comentas, parece que la consulta no te está devolviendo nada, o al menos, no lo que que se espera. Como dice frikinside, deberías imprimir el objeto $row para ver que contiene. De todos modos, no te recomiendo poner campos en una taba que contengan ñ. Te aconsejo que lo llames mejor contrasenaprofe.

Comment: Además de que no conviene usar caracteres especiales en el nombre de los campos, si tu tabla tiene el campo 'contraseñaprofesor', como defines al inicio, no va a encontrar en el select 'contraseñaprofe' porque no es el nombre del campo.

Comment: Prueba a dar un `Select * ...` en vez de el select de contraseñaprofe Definitivamente debes eliminar las "eñes" de tu código. Recuerda que es un caracter especial y debe manejarse con cuidado. En lo posible sólo utiliza "ñ" cuando necesites mostrar un string en la vista que así lo amerite.

Comment: **¿Cómo se llama la columna en la tabla: `contraseñaprofe` o `contraseñaprofesor`**?  En el planteamiento de la pregunta dices: *En profesor uso el 'id_profesor' que es la llave primaria y **'contraseñaprofesor'** para validar el ingreso...* y en el código usas: `SELECT contraseñaprofe FROM profesor WHERE id_profesor = '$usenum'` Eso sería lo primero, que te aclares sobre cómo se llama la columna realmente. Luego podremos tratar otras deficiencias y fallos de seguridad que tiene el código.

Comment: Hice cambios a la BD y ahora la columna se llama "contrasenap" me marca un error de tipo "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaPrueba\checklogin_profe.php on line 18" le hice un var_dump a $result y me arroja un "bool(false)"

Comment: Parece que la línea 18 es esta: `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    ` si es así, significa que también hay un problema con esta consulta: `SELECT * FROM administrador WHERE usuario = '$username'` ... ¿Existe realmente una tabla llamada `administrador`?  ¿Esa tabla tiene una columna llamada `usuario`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el if, estás evaluando de esta manera:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {    
 $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

y luego continuas verificando la contraseña. El cierre de ese if debería estás más abajo, tu código debería ser el siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start();

$host_db = "localhost";
$user_db = "root";
$pass_db = "";
$db_name = "tutorias";
$tbl_name = "profesor";

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);
if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("No se pudo conectar a la Base de Datos: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$usenum = $_POST['num'];
$pass = $_POST['contra'];

$sql = "SELECT contraseñaprofe FROM profesor WHERE id_profesor = '$usenum'";
$result = $conexion->query($sql);

if ($result) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (password_verify($pass, $row['contraseñaprofe'])) {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

        echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
        echo "<br><br><a href=home_profes.php>Panel de Control</a>";    
    }else{
        echo "Username o Password estan incorrectos.";
        echo "<br><a href='login_profe.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
    }
}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Tienes el mismo problema en **checklogin.php**

Comment: Hola, ya hice los cambios y me arroja este error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaPrueba\checklogin_profe.php on line 18" Creo que es como comentan, que por alguna razón la consulta no se está efectuando

Comment: He modificado el código nuevamente, si continua el problema, incluye la linea del código correspondiente al error

Comment: Al parecer ya funciona como debería.  :D